# EXTJS custom code in XTemplate - "<tpl for=..."

Tags: extjs

How to execute loop in XTemplate particular number of times

Following does not work

```
<tpl for="5">
...
</tpl>
```

Regards,
kkris1983

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think this works is where you fill a variable with 5 items, like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'test',
        height: 300,
        width: 300
    });

    var total = 5;
    var data = {
        count: []
    };    
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        data.count.push(i);
    }

    var tpl = [
        '<tpl for="count">',
        '{.}<br>',            
        '</tpl>'];

    var t = new Ext.XTemplate(tpl);
    panel.update(t.apply(data));
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/2WEVE/3/